# Function declaration + Address-of operator

Tags: c++

What exactly does function "func" return?

```
int a = 10;
int &func() {
    return a;
}

int main() {
    int b = func();
    std::cout << b; // prints 10
}
```

Comment: It's a reference. Speaking of which, allow me to refer you to our [excellent book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thanks guys. I thought that references and pointers are the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` means a reference here, not the address operator. So `func()` returns a reference to an int. When you call it, it returns a reference to the variable `a`, and when you assign it to the int `b`, it copies the value in `a` to `b`.